# Wiring for radio issues?

Tags: electrical, audio, jeep, cherokee

I have a 04 jeep grand cherokee special edition and the factory harness was cut out so I figured whatever I'll just hard wire it. Found all the speaker wire colors matches them up but the battery wires which I assumed were the two red and white ones don't have power running to them but the two black ones do. I thought those were the ground. The illumination has constant power. So, I hooked them up with the black to battery since it's constant and the red and white to ground but it keeps popping the fuse in the back of the radio. Am I missing something ? I can't find and diagrams or forums with this issue. Please help !!!

Comment: BTW, Khayla ... Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: No it's an after market radio but when I first hooked it up obv red and white to battery etc there was no power to the head unit. So, I took a test light to the wires and no power to the red and white but power to both black also 12v on the meter and when i tested for ground wires the red and white lit up , I figured constant power to battery etc but now it's popping the fuse. I'm not an idiot but this don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the diagrams for the base sound system, colors are the same for Premium Sound.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. +1 for answering and making it complete with diagrams :o)

Comment: There should be 2 power wires on the new head unit, one is batt and should be yellow, the other is accy and should be red, connect them separately, there should be only one black wire on the new head unit, connect it to either one of the black harness wires.

Comment: I'm asking about from the jeep

Comment: 2 Red/white to yellow, white/red to red and 2 black to black or should i ground one black to the back of radio and other to the ground of harness ?

Comment: just the black wire out of the radio to one of the black wires in the Jeep harness.